# playing video in android from local disc

Tags: android

Am able to play videos from URLs but not able to play from local disc. The file is stored in the C:/users/workspace/test/res/raw/test4.mp4
how do I parse this path in Uri.parse??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The file is stored in the
>   C:/users/workspace/test/res/raw/test4.mp4

No, it is not. It may be stored on your Windows PC at that path, but that path is not on your Android phone, since your Android phone does not have a C: drive. You need to put that file onto your phone or emulator, preferably to the SD card (or emulated equivalent). To do that, you can use DDMS's File Manager (available from the standalone DDMS or the DDMS Eclipse perspective), or use the `adb push` command.